# Configuration of Google spreadsheets with Odoo

Tags: google-sheets, odoo-8

I want to get the report data in google spreadsheets in Odoo.
I have done following steps to configure google spreadsheet with Odoo:

- Installed the Google Spreadsheet module in Odoo.
- Generated Google Authorization Code
- Tried to get a report on Google Spreadsheet but it gives me Error Some settings are not set in Code. From settings did it manually
  Server Settings -->
- URL --> http://127.0.0.1:8069
- dbname ---> Database name
- username -username of database
- password - password of database

Am I doing something wrong? I don't have much idea. Please guide.

Comment: Could you explain where exactly you got the "server settings" in Google Spreadsheet? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: For that you have to code in googlescript and give Settings panel in the menu. Go to Tools, you will find script editor, you can add the code in that.

Comment: First can you please tell me about your purpose, what you are planning to develop from Web App

Comment: I am trying get Odoo data into spreadsheets by writing queries in the <Function> area like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6lkB05Emuo. Basically I want to connect it to my Odoo and pull data from my postgres database.

Comment: Ok got it. I have worked for the same. Will be able to share it later, dont have my laptop right now at office :(

Comment: And sorry forgot to mention , we wont require to go to Web App, you have to select a blank project from the Script Editor

Comment: Yeah I figured as much. blank project. I'm a newbie at this so pardon my mistake. :/ Anyway, thanks a lot for you patience! I am looking forward to seeing the code from you today! Thanks again!

Comment: Hi I am sorry please forward your gamil id i will mail you the code

Comment: yes sure i will send you the code and hope you know how to make settings on Odoo side for google spreadsheets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Configuration for Google Spreadsheet with Odoo requires live IP address of your database (server) so the it can make authentication and then pull data or synchronize in Google Spreadsheets.