# How to connect Google Spreadsheets to Odoo?

Tags: google-sheets, odoo, odoo-8, erp

I want to connect my Google Spreadsheets to Odoo v8. I saw [this Odoo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6lkB05Emuo) where they are using the spreadsheet after getting connected, but it does not teach HOW to connect spreadsheet to Odoo. There is no proper documentation either.

What are the steps to connect Odoo with spreadsheet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configuration of Google spreadsheets with Odoo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122072/configuration-of-google-spreadsheets-with-odoo)

Comment: I was hoping for more details. :/

Answer (score 0):

I have configured the integration to my Google docs account and I can attach new google documents to an object using the attachment menu (e.g to a sales order.). The document receives automatically the name of the sales order + date+ time.

However I can't seem to do this when creating new google docs templates.

For example:

I want to create a new Google doc text document using a predefined template which is to be attached to sales orders:

1. Configuration of Google doc URL in Menu: Settings/Google Docs Configuration/ Model Configurations
2. i create a new model configuration record
3. I enter the name of the model. - In this example I entered - Sales Order
4. So according to the instructions in the view, I enter the URL of the Google docs document that has been created: for example

I enter:
document:1vJECkFoq-OWeQQKi-rZ8BNpAF0884AhAjJPvRFgaLZU

that points to a document (this is just an example):
https://docs.google.com/a/an_example_company/document/d/1vJECkFoq-OWeQQKi-rZ8BNpAF0884AhAjJPvRFgaLZU/edit

This is according to the instructions in the configuration view.

5. I leave default value of gdoc_%(name)s for the pattern
6. I create a sales order and try to attach a Google docs document by pressing the attachment drop down and select " add google docs"